# List index out of bounds in TPageControl

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tpagecontrol

I am stuck with a TPageControl that exhibits some strange behaviour..

The control has 3 pages but when I do

```
for I:=0 to PageControl.PageCount-1 do begin
  PageControl.Pages[I].TabVisible := False;
  PageControl.Pages[I].Visible    := Ord(iColorScale.GenerationMode) = I;
end;
```

I get a 'List index out of bounds (3)' error when executing the first line of the first iteration of the loop equivalent to

```
PageControl.Pages[0].TabVisible := False;
```

Now, when I view the PageControl properties in the debugger, everything seems to be in order. The PageCount is expectedly 3, and I can see all the pages and their properties, including TabVisible of page 0, in the evaluator

I'm using Delphi XE on a windows 7 machine.. Does anyone have an idea what is going on? I'm at a loss.

Comment: What happens if you try to run `PageControl.Pages[0].TabVisible := False;` outside of a loop?

Comment: Try setting `PageControl.HandleNeeded` before setting `TabVisible` to false. (http://www.delphigroups.info/2/d7/305018.html)

Comment: @Fenistil I get the same list index out of bounds error when running 
    PageControl.Pages[0].TabVisible := False;
outside the loop

Comment: @kobik PageControl.HandleNeeded solved the problem, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @kobik, can you expend that comment into an answer?

Comment: @Johan, done. I think it's a good question and deserves a reference on SO also (in case delphigroups link will die). personally I could not reproduce this error (D5/XP).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tldr: set `PageControl.HandleNeeded` before setting `TabVisible`.

There is a good explanation here (by Greg Chapman): [TabVisible on TabSheet and index error](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/d7/305018.html)
For future SO reference (copy/paste):

If the PageControl's handle was destroyed (which can
happen if setting some property in the PageControl or any of its parent windows causes a call to `RecreateWnd`), the PageControl saves the visible tabs in a `TStringList` (`FSaveTabs`).  Setting `TabVisible` results in a call to this routine:

```
procedure TTabSheet.SetTabShowing(Value: Boolean);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  if FTabShowing <> Value then
    if Value then
    begin
      FTabShowing := True;
      FPageControl.InsertTab(Self);
    end else
    begin
      Index := TabIndex;
      FTabShowing := False;
      FPageControl.DeleteTab(Self, Index);
    end;
end;
```

During the call to `FPageControl.DeleteTab`, the PageControl will recreate its handle if necessary. In doing so, it tries to reset the visible tabs using `FSaveTabs`. However, it can get confused because one of the tabs that it added to `FSaveTabs` is now invisible (`TabSheet.FTabShowing = false`).  This causes the IndexError. So the fix is to make sure the handle is recreated before setting `TabVisible`.

Comment: Really nice answer!